# Show that endomorphism is automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let dim V = n, $a\in End(V)$, and for some $v\in V$ set of $a(v)$, $a^2(v)$, $\ldots$, $a^n(v)$ is linearly independent. (where $a^i(v) = a\circ a\circ \ldots\circ a$ i times, $\circ$ is a composition. Show that a has invertible. I need to show that a is injection, if I will prove it I can prove that this is surjetive, then I will show that this is bijection and this will mean that we have invertible $a^{-1}$. but the problem is that I dont know how to prove that this is injection. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: It's probably easier to show directly that $a$ is surjective (from which it will follow that $a$ is also injective).  For that, note that $\{ a(v), a^2(v), \ldots, a^n(v) \}$ must be a basis of $V$...

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $a(v),\ldots,a^n(v)$ lies in the image of $a$ and they form a basis of $V$. So $a$ is suryective and, because the dimension is finite, it is an automorphism.

Comment: Thank you! But I did not understood why this is basis leads to surjectivity?

Comment: The image of a vector space under a linear function is always a linear subspace. Do you see why? So if you have a generating set in the image this is equivalent to surjectivity.